# SMBus driver issue

Tags: windows-7, drivers, lenovo-laptop

I've been having an issue with one of the drivers on my Lenovo G475  laptop (Windows 7).

I tried installing a windows driver update for the "AMD SMBus" but the installation failed with the error code 80070103.

When I go to system devices and double click on the AMD SMBus device and then on driver > driver details, it says, "no driver files are required or have been loaded for this device").

Apparently, the SMBus driver is a chipset driver but there are no chipset drivers available on the Lenovo support website for the G475 model.

Everything seems to be working normally and there are no yellow warning icons next to any of the devices in the device manager.

Comment: This device seems to be supported directly by Windows and doesn't need a driver. Downloading drivers from doubtful websites is a very very bad idea, and dangerous for your computer. Why do you think you need such a driver?

Comment: The laptop is manufactured by Lenovo and I downloaded drivers from the Lenovo website after reformatting the hard drive.

Comment: But why do you search for such a driver if Windows insists that its driver is good enough and Lenovo agrees doesn't supply such a driver.

Comment: Windows update tried and failed to install an update for the driver. I then checked to see what the driver's status was in "system devices". It read, "no driver files are required or have been loaded for this device".  So, basically, I am asking if that's something I should be concerned about or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as your device is functioning, there is no problem.
The SMBus is an essential component and without it your computer would have
been dead.

The fact that Windows Update tried and failed to install a driver for it,
may perhaps mean that its choice of driver was incorrect.

If Windows Update continues to give error messages on this driver,
you may block this specific update by right-clicking it and selecting
"Hide Update".